# I am trying to install vue3 js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to install vue3 js. but unfortunately I am getting an error please help me how can i resolve ? thanks.

**developer@developer-ThinkCentre-M93p:**~$ npm install -g @vue/cli

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8HIwwH2SLKEsPpZqiiIW8'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T02_11_15_446Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tired npm install vue

Comment: yes I have  installed this  please check https://ibb.co/gZY81bL

Comment: you're saying that you're trying to install vue 3, but your image shows vue 2.6

Comment: what version of node are you on, do node -v if it doesnt show there is either something wrong with node or you dont have it installed

Comment: i have node version v10.19.0

Comment: getting an error  ibb.co/zF14P17

Comment: i faced same thing once, I think you don't have an updated version of npm so `Npm install -g npm@latest` then `npm install` after doing this try to install vue.js `Npm i -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `vue-cli` if you haven't yet

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

**OR** update to latest

```
sudo npm update -g @vue/cli
```

then create a new project with

```
vue create hello-world
```

then select vue 3 project

[image]

---

Including comment from @Eazash:

> *You need to verify your npm cache with `npm cache verify` and then try installing vue-cli. If that doesn't work, try clearing the cache altogether with `npm cache clean --force`*

could also try with sudo privileges: `sudo npm cache verify` and `sudo npm cache clean --force`

Comment: again i have used these commands but unfortunately getting an error https://ibb.co/zF14P17

Comment: try `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: You need to verify your npm cache with ```npm cache verify``` and then try installing vue-cli. If that doesn't work, try clearing the cache altogether with ```npm cache clean --force```.

Comment: sir, I have cleared cache and then install vue js but facing like this https://ibb.co/bJL7Hcp